# how to access aspnet_reqsql tables in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using ASP.Net reg sql. I designed a login service to my site. I denied to table service of C# and joining by designed my table this service and insert ,delete, update.what can i do it in asp.net?

Comment: Do you means `ASPNETDB.MDF` ?

Comment: no,im using asp.net login tools,and my db table name is aspnet_Membership,aspnet_Roles,aspnet_Applications and ....

Comment: Tell me how do you access to this tables ?

Comment: I go to start menu,Visual studio folder 2un the and visual studio tools and run the Developer command promot for vs 2012 and next, aspnet_reqsql command. of this way i create manual table and i work login controls and wilzard user.now,i want to created  manual tabls connected and type data.

Comment: so you are using the asp.net membership database and want to extend it?

Comment: Can you try to explain what exactly you're trying to do, because it's a bit unclear to me. Do you mean you want tobe able to query the membership tables? Then you could for example add them to an Entity Framework edmx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a database in your project , you can combine membership tables to it ,
All this code to your `web.config` , and re-run `aspnet_reqsql` . All of your membership tables will combine to your database as given connection string :)

```
<membership>
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
      type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"  
      connectionStringName="SameASYourDatabaseConnectionString" enablePasswordRetrieval="false"   
      enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"   
      requiresUniqueEmail="true" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"   
      minRequiredPasswordLength="3" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"   
      passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" /> 
</providers>
</membership>
```

Notice that , `connectionStringName="SameASYourDatabaseConnectionString"` .

Comment: ok , thanks,and one question,after i do it this step,what should I do?

Comment: Do you have a database in your project that can access ?

Comment: I see ,all your your membership tables are already in your database , now you can access and process to it . What would you like to do ?

Comment: when user register with CreateUserWizard, the information save into Aspnet_membership and Aspnet_users,i want save more information from user such as name,family,major and save this data based on username and userid that saved in Aspnet_membership and Aspnet_users and insert into "Industrialist" table.